# Wrong expected result from DateTime diff

Tags: php, datetime

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2014-02-28");
$date2 = new DateTime("2014-04-02");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
```

This results in 1 month and 5 days.

I expected it to result in 1 month and 2 days, where the one month is to 2014-03-31 and two days to get up to 2014-04-02

It seems like the month is set to 2014-03-28, and then 5 days to get to 2014-04-02.

How can I get the result I expect?

Comment: Use the format() method of the DateInterval with `a` to get the total number of days, then mod that by your own days per month value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2014-02-28");
$date2 = new DateTime("2014-04-02");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);

echo $interval->format('%m'), ' months and ', $interval->format('%a') % 31, ' days';
```

Answer (score 0):

see this code snippet ,use `strtotime()`

```
<?php 
$result= strtotime("2014-04-02")-strtotime("2014-02-28");
$resul1=$result/(3600*24);
echo $resul1;

?>
```

Demo here: http://codepad.org/fwKY75sX